# Pointdns with heroku point to No App

Tags: heroku, node.js

I have deployed my app on heroku and got a custom domain with pointdns.
point dns seems to redirect the doamin correctly, but heroku seems to get invalid app or empty page that says " There's nothing here, yet. ".

NOTE: my app is working with the domain provided from heroku.

[my doamin dns records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3ccN.png)

[heroku error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb2YM.png)

[point dns records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLPr4.png)

Answer (score 0):

Adding both

```
<mydomain>.cf
```

and

```
 www.<mydomain>.cf
```

to heroku custom domains solved the problem.